# What is the difference between using coroutineScope() and launching a child coroutine and calling join on it?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I am trying to understand the `coroutineScope()` suspend function in Kotlin and I'm having a hard time understanding the exact purpose of this function.

As per the kotlinlang docs,

> This function is designed for parallel decomposition of work. When any
> child coroutine in this scope fails, this scope fails and all the rest
> of the children are cancelled (for a different behavior see
> supervisorScope). This function returns as soon as the given block and
> all its children coroutines are completed.

But I feel this behavior can be achieved by launching a child coroutine and calling join on it.

So for example

```
suspend fun other() {
    coroutineScope {
        launch { // some task }
        async { // some task }
    }
}
```

This can be written as (scope is a reference to the scope created by the parent coroutine)

```
suspend fun other(scope: CoroutineScope) {
    scope.launch {
        launch { // some task }
        async { // some task }
    }.join()
}
```

- Is there any difference between these two approaches since it looks
  like they will produce same result and also seem to work in the same fashion?
- If not, is `coroutineScope`    merely a way to reduce this
  boilerplate code of passing scope from    parent coroutine and
  calling join on child coroutine?

Comment: It's not just boilerplate. The behavior will be different if you pass a CoroutineScope other than the current coroutine's scope (it won't cause the top level coroutine to throw if the coroutine in some other scope throws). Also, `coroutineScope` returns a result and `launch` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**

Using `CoroutineScope` as in the example adds boilerplate code, is more confusing, error-prone and may handle cases like errors and cancellations differently. `coroutineScope()` is generally preferred in such cases.

**Full answer**

These two patterns are conceptually different and are used in different cases. Coroutines are all about sequential code and structured concurrency. Sequential means we can write a traditional code that waits in-place, it doesn't use callbacks, etc. and at the same time we don't get a performance hit. Structured concurrency means concurrent tasks have their owners, tasks consists of smaller sub-tasks that are explicit to the framework.

By mixing both above together we get a very easy to use and error-proof concurrency model where in most cases we don't have to launch background jobs and then manage them manually, watch for errors, handle cancellations, etc. We simply fork into sub-tasks and then join them in-place - that's all.

In Kotlin this is represented by suspend functions. Suspend functions are always executed within some context, this context is passed everywhere implicitly and the coroutines framework provides utils to use this context easily. One of the most common patterns is to fork and then join and this is exactly what `coroutineScope()` does. It creates a scope for launching sub-tasks and we can't leave this scope until all children are successful. We don't have to pass the scope manually, we don't have to join, we don't have to pass errors from children to their siblings and to parent, we don't have to pass cancellations from the parent to children - this is all automatic.

Therefore, suspend functions and `coroutineScope()` should be the default way of writing concurrent code with coroutines. This approach is easy to write, easy to read and it is error-proof. We can't easily leak a background task, because `coroutineScope()` won't let us go anywhere. We can't mistakenly ignore errors from background tasks. Etc.

Of course, in some cases we can't use this pattern. Sometimes, we actually would like to only launch a long-running task and return immediately. Sometimes, we don't consider the caller to be the owner of the task. For example, we could have some kind of a service that manages its tasks and we only schedule these tasks, but the service itself owns them. For these cases we can use `CoroutineScope`.

By using the scope explicitly we can launch tasks in the different context than the current one or from outside of coroutine world. We generally have more control, but at the same time we partially opt-out of the code correctness guarantees I mentioned above. For example, if we forget to invoke `join()` we can easily leak background tasks or perform operations in unexpected order. Also, in your case if the coroutine invoking `other()` is cancelled, all launched operations will be still running in the background. For these reasons, we should use `CoroutineScope` explicitly only if needed.

**Common patterns**

As a result of all that was said above, when working with coroutines we usually use one of these patterns:

- Suspend function - it runs within the caller context and it waits for all its subtasks, it doesn't launch anything in the background.
- Function receiving `CoroutineScope` either as a param or receiver - usually, that means the function wants to do something with the context even after returning (because otherwise it could be simply a suspend function). It either launches some background tasks or stores the context somewhere for a later use.
- Regular function that uses its own `CoroutineScope` to launch tasks. Usually, this is some kind of a service that keeps its custom context.

At least to me, function which is suspend and receives `CoroutineScope` is pretty confusing, it is not entirely clear what to expect from it. Will it execute the operation in the caller context or in the provided one? Will it wait to finish or only schedule the operation in the background and return immediately? Maybe it will do both: first do some initial processing synchronously (therefore `suspend`), but also schedule additional task in the background (therefore `scope: CoroutineScope`)? We don't know this, we have to read the documentation or source code to understand its behavior. Your second example is unnecessary complication over a simple suspend function.

To further make my point consider this example:

```kotlin
data class User(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
) {
    fun getFullName(user: User) = ...
}
```

This example is far from perfect, but the main point is that it is confusing why we have to pass `user` to `getFullName()` if we call this function on a user already. We don't know whether it returns a full name of the passed user, the user we invoked the function on or maybe some kind of a mix? If that would be a member function not receiving a `User` or a static utility function receiving a `User`, everything would be clear. But a member function receiving a `User` is simply confusing. This is similar to your second example where we pass the context both implicitly and explicitly and we don't know which one is used and how exactly.